# How to verify mobile number by sending OTP in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, rest

I am developing Android application where the application should display some contents after verifying the user mobile number using OTP. I am using MySQL as database and accessing the database using PHP and parsing the reply from PHP using JSON. I am using REST service for developing this application. Can you help me out to find the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to verify your phone number with a misscall? or by typing a OTP that you got as a message?

Comment: Only by OTP @HariKrishnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your jobs can be done by this [library](https://github.com/cognalys/Cogdemov2)
You can verify your phone number by using this cognalys library. I think this is the best method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will implement and proceed the way to reach point

Comment: Yes sure. I'll Marj as answer once I get solution

Comment: is it possible that we can implement this service by our self if we have node server, as this library is paid.

Comment: it is paid, but for a limited use you can use it for free.

Comment: and of course you can implement one yourself  by customizing it which is against their policies. :D